# mysql default value error

Tags: mysql, sinatra

I'm testing a link-shortener Sinatra application that uses a mysql database. When I enter a link to be shortened, I'm getting this mysql error

```
 (mysql_errno=1364, sql_state=HY000) Field 'link_identifier' doesn't have a default value Query: INSERT INTO `urls` (`original`) VALUES ('http://pryrepl.org/screencasts.html')
```

I'm assuming that means field link_identifier should have a default value

urls and visits tables both have link_identifier field, but the links table doesn't. However, in the code that creates the tables, copied below, it's the Link class that has the `property  :identifier.' Does anyone know how I would fix this problem?

```
mysql> show columns from urls;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| original        | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| link_identifier | varchar(50)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.12 sec)

mysql> show columns from visits
    -> ;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at      | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ip              | varchar(39)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| country         | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| link_identifier | varchar(50)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.08 sec)

mysql> show columns from links
    -> ;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| identifier | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| created_at | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Code**

```
class Url
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property  :id,          Serial
  property  :original,    String, :length => 255   
  belongs_to  :link
end
....

class Link
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property  :identifier,  String, :key => true
  property  :created_at,  DateTime 
  has 1, :url
  has n, :visits

...

class Visit
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property  :id,          Serial
  property  :created_at,  DateTime
  property  :ip,          IPAddress
  property  :country,     String
  belongs_to  :link

  after :create, :set_country

....
```

Update -  the source code already seems to have a way to create a link identifier to satisfy the requirements of mysql, but it doesn't seem to be working

```
def self.create_link(original)
    url = Url.create(:original => original)
    if Link.first(:identifier => url.id.to_s(36)).nil? or !DIRTY_WORDS.include? url.id.to_s(36)
      link = Link.new(:identifier => url.id.to_s(36))
      link.url = url
      link.save 
      return link     
    else
      create_link(original)
    end    
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means you are not setting a value for `link_identifier` in your insert statement. And `link_identifier` cannot be `null` by table definition.

You need to specify a value for `link_identifier`. Example

```
INSERT INTO `urls` (`original`, `link_identifier`) 
VALUES ('http://pryrepl.org/screencasts.html', 'value_for_link_identifier')
```

Comment: thanks, I updated the OP. The problem seems to be with the source code, which, although it tries to create the link_identifier, is not working as planned

Answer (score 0):

When sending the query

```
 INSERT INTO `urls` (`original`) VALUES ('http://pryrepl.org/screencasts.html')
```

the value for `link_identifier` isn't set.

You defined the urls table as

```
mysql> show columns from urls;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| original        | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| link_identifier | varchar(50)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.12 sec)
```

The default value for link_identifier is NULL (or not set), but since the value cannot be NULL, mysql doesn't know what to set as value.

Change the mysql query into

```
 INSERT INTO `urls` (`original`, `link_identifier`) VALUES ('http://pryrepl.org/screencasts.html', '<your identifier here>')
```

Comment: thanks, I updated the OP. The problem seems to be with the source code, which, although it tries to create the link_identifier, is not working as planned